# Make keyboard not push up view

Tags: android, android-layout

Since picture is worth a thousands words:

[image]

So I want my first LinearLayout to act something like a action bar, not being pushed up by keyboard. I tried `android:isScrollContainer="false"` and adding in manifest `"adjustPan"` or `"adjustResize"`, but i don't get what i want.

Here is my XML:

```
<!-- layout 1 -->
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/caller_info"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:isScrollContainer="false"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/last_message_margin">
        <TextView android:text="@string/hello_world" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/txt_caller_name"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/side_margins"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/side_margins"/>
</LinearLayout>


<!-- layout 2 -->
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/dialog"
    android:layout_below="@+id/caller_info"
    android:layout_above="@+id/write_msg_layout">
</LinearLayout>


<!-- layout 3 with edit text -->
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:id="@+id/write_msg_layout">

    <EditText
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/side_margins"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/side_margins"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/edit_text"
        android:hint="Write Msg"
        android:textColorHint="@color/grey_as_clouds"
        android:background="@color/white_as_stone"
        android:imeOptions="actionSend"
        android:singleLine="true" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it. You must surround your view with ScrollView and use `adjustResize`.

And delete `android:isScrollContainer="false"`.